# Angular ng-repeat, nested repeat for each parent loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some trouble with getting proper data. I have many-to-many relation model, so it's 3 tables, two with data, and third is connection between them (by ID's). For example, first table is stores, second is items, and third is 'have' that connects them by id.

Now i should display available items per store. I'm using ng-repeat="store in stores" to loop through stores, and trying to create function that will return me items available in each store (store.idStore).

I have tried several approaches and none of them seems to be working for me, and since I'm new to angular, Im a little bit lost. I would appreciate any help.

Last function that I used is:

```
function forEachStore(id) {
                        angular.forEach($scope.Have, function (value, index) {
                            if (idStore == id) {                          

alert(idPlayliste);
                                this.push(dataFact.catchData(urlItem, idItem));
                            }
                        }, $scope.storeHasItem)
                    }
```

$scope.Have --> contains json object like({"id":1, "idStore":1, "idItem":1}, {"id":2, "idStore":1, "idItem":2}, ...)

dataFact.catchData--> my factory that gets api url and idItem and returns json object(this is working correctly).

id == store.idStore sent from ng-repeat.

So, I'm sending to this function 'store.idStore', and I want it to return me all items that is available in that store.

No alert for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it looks like `$scope.stores` is an array of Store objects. I'm assuming you have something similar for items. In your first ng-repeat loop, add something like `ng-repeat="item in getItemsForStore(store.idStore)"` to start the inner loop, and add the following functions to your scope (not yet tested):

```
$scope.getItemsForStore = function(storeId) {
  var items = [];
  for (var have = $scope.have, i = 0, len = have.length; i < len; i++) {
    var link = have[i];
    if (link.idStore === storeId && !items.contains(link.idItem) {
      items.push(link.idItem);
    }
  }
  for (int j = 0, len = items.length; j < len; j++) {
    items[j] = getItem(items[j]);
  }
  return items;
}

function getItem(itemId) {
  for (var i = 0, items = $scope.items, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item.idItem === itemId) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  throw "unknown item ID: " + itemId;
}
```

Things could be far more efficient if you used objects instead of arrays, with items/stores keyed by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
On a comment inspired second read :).

I think`idStore` should be `value.idStore`(here:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Have, function (value, index) {
                            if (idStore == id) {     ... })};
```

)

And also: 
angular.forEach(obj, iterator, [context]), where context will provide 'this' for the iterator. You're setting context to $scope.storeHasItem - a function on the $scope, I guess it's not what you're after.

Old answer:

When you're using  `ng-repeat="store in stores"` - you get something like this:  store = stores[0] in the scope + a dom template in the view (a copy of the element on which you've put the repeat)...then store = stores[1] and a copy...and so on

So in the function, the parameter you're getting is a whole store object, not just the id. Try a console.log - it should clarify things.

Comment: The question could be clearer, but it appears that he is trying to call a function in his `$scope` object which takes a store ID. As he iterates through the first ng-repeat, he's calling that function with `store.idStore`. Thus I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Thank you both, I will try this now.
I will try to clear my question a little bit. On ng-repeat, angular takes objects from json object called stores, and on each iteration fill view with data from current iteration, and you can access current iteration data by defining for example {{store.id}}, and id of current iteration will be displayed. On the similar way I'm trying to call my function, sending her current id on call. 
For now, for testing purposes, I have hardcoded this, and I'm sending this function number 1 on controller call.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Ctrl($scope){
    $scope.stores =[
        {id:1,name:'store 1'},
        {id:2,name:'store 2'},
        {id:3,name:'store 3'},
        {id:4,name:'store 4'}
    ];
    $scope.items =[
        {id:1, name:'item 1'},
        {id:2, name:'item 2'},
        {id:3, name:'item 3'},
        {id:4, name:'item 4'},
        {id:5, name:'item 5'},
        {id:6, name:'item 6'},
    ];
    
    var storeItemLinked= [
        {sId:1,iId:1},
        {sId:1,iId:2},
        {sId:1,iId:3},
        {sId:2,iId:4},
        {sId:2,iId:5},
        {sId:2,iId:6},
        {sId:3,iId:1},
        {sId:3,iId:3},
        {sId:3,iId:5},
        {sId:4,iId:2},
        {sId:4,iId:4},
        {sId:4,iId:5}           
        
    ];
    $scope.selectedStoreItems=[];
    $scope.showStoreItems=function(store){
        $scope.selectedStoreItems=[];
        $scope.selectedStore=store;
        var itemIds=[];
        for(var i=0;i<storeItemLinked.length;i++){
            if(storeItemLinked[i].sId==store.id)
                itemIds.push(storeItemLinked[i].iId);
        }
                for(var j=0;j<$scope.items.length;j++){
            if(itemIds.indexOf($scope.items[j].id)>=0)
               $scope.selectedStoreItems.push($scope.items[j]);
        }
    }
    
    $scope.showAvailableStores = function(item){
        $scope.selectedItem=item;
        $scope.selectedItemStores=[];
        
        var storeIds=[];
        for(var i=0;i<storeItemLinked.length;i++){
            if(storeItemLinked[i].iId==item.id)
                storeIds.push(storeItemLinked[i].sId);
        }
                for(var j=0;j<$scope.stores.length;j++){
            if(storeIds.indexOf($scope.stores[j].id)>=0)
               $scope.selectedItemStores.push($scope.stores[j]);
        }
    }
    
    
        
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="store in stores" ng-click="showStoreItems(store)">{{store.name}}
            <ul ng-show="selectedStore==store">
                <li ng-repeat="item in selectedStoreItems" ng-click="showAvailableStores(item)">
                    {{item.name}}
                    <ul ng-show="selectedItem==item">
                        <li ng-repeat="store in selectedItemStores">{{store.name}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

click the store will list all available items then click an item will list all stores that sell that item

I just mocked up the database by some js objects and you may want to change those ng-click functions to get remote data and the logic inside will depends on the view model return from server